# Building dotnet core project under macOS

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, macos-sierra

Getting the following error when trying to run `dotnet build` or `dotnet restore` command from terminal.

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libproc': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Interop.libproc.proc_pidpath(Int32 pid, Byte* buffer, UInt32 bufferSize)
   at Interop.libproc.proc_pidpath(Int32 pid)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ResolvePath(String filename)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.ProcessStartInfoExtensions.Execute(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildForwardingApp.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Restore.RestoreCommand.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Any ideas how to fix it?
The version of dotnet core is 2.0.0.